# Include json file in webextension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

How to include json file (a dictionary) and then access data from it in my webextension? (Should work on Firefox/Chrome and preferrably others)

Comment: [Read file at startup Chrome extension/kiosk app](//stackoverflow.com/a/37674803)

Comment: Specify file in ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). Pack it with the extension. And once you need it &ndash; you can load via Fetch/XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to load your JSON data as a variable in a regular javascript file:

json.js:

```
var data = {
  1: "hello",
  2: "world"
}
```

Then include it as you would include any other script.